# Get the entire page overriding any limitation (python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get the entire page content from this page: https://www.csaregistries.ca/GHG_VR_Listing/CleanProjectProjects

It seems that the page automatically limits the displayed content while scrolling.
For instance, 1st code returns names starting with A - C, whereas 2nd code returns L - W. Is there any way to pull out the entire page content. (**I'm not asking `page_source` to be answered or scroll down or even the `time.sleep`, but I'm asking you how to override the page's unknown limitation by selenium**)

And the codes used are as below:

1st (w/o going to the page bottom):

```
url = "https://www.csaregistries.ca/GHG_VR_Listing/CleanProjectProjects"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
       
content = browser.page_source.encode('utf-8')
file_ = open('result1.html', 'wb')
file_.write(content)
file_.close()
browser.close()
```

2nd (w/ going to the page bottom):

```
url = "https://www.csaregistries.ca/GHG_VR_Listing/CleanProjectProjects"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/footer/div/div/div/div[3]')
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.click(elem).perform()
time.sleep(5)
  
content = browser.page_source.encode('utf-8')
file_ = open('result1.html', 'wb')
file_.write(content)
file_.close()
browser.close()
```

Comment: That's entirely up to the site.  You might be able to troll through the Javascript and figure out how they decide on the paging.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi! Sorry for the late response, but could you please elaborate on that? What do you mean by trolling through the JavaScript via python code?

Comment: No, I mean go download and read their Javascript code by hand, and figure out where they are getting the "entries per page" value.  It may be something you can override, or maybe it isn't  You won't know until you read their code.